# Resize tmux splits with YADR

Tags: vim, tmux, iterm2, yadr

### Issue

I'm new to using tmux/vim and have found that I love it a lot more after using [skwp's dotfiles](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles) (YADR). The only thing I'm having trouble figuring out is resizing the tmux splits and would love some help.

### What I've tried

Per the documented [.tmux.conf](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux/tmux.conf)

```
# Pane resize in all four directions using vi bindings.
# Can use these raw but I map them to shift-ctrl-<h,j,k,l> in iTerm.
bind -r H resize-pane -L 5
bind -r J resize-pane -D 5
bind -r K resize-pane -U 5
bind -r L resize-pane -R 5
```

- From what I understand `bind` is an alias for `bind-key` which YADR has the prefix as `C-a`
- Per the tmux manual the `-r` indicates this key may repeat.
- `H` = `shift`+ `h`
- `resize-pane` is the tmux command
- Lastly, `-L` indicated left

### Results

- What I get is the just switching between the various panes I have open instead of resizing the window.

What am i missing!?! Treat me like a super newb to this stuff because I am.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're forgetting to press that <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

To resize the pane, you should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, then release them, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to resize pane to the left.